# Rerouting all ASP.NET pages

Tags: c#, asp.net, routes, url-routing

I am looking to rewrite all ASP.NET pages to a uniform structure. Something like:

- /Content1/Page1.aspx  -> /Page1
- /Content1/Page2.aspx  -> /Page2
- /Content2/Page3.aspx  -> /Page3 (note
  different sub-dir)
- /xyz/Page4.aspx       -> /Page4

Is this possible?

---

URL Rewriting seems interesting... Will it also comply with my web.config security rules (ie. address access only to /Content2/Page5.aspx should remain in force when browsing to /Page5).

Comment: What version of IIS are you using?

Comment: You can enforce URLRewriting as strict or as loose as you like since it's all done via Regular Expressions.  See my edited answer for another option (URLMappings)

Comment: Regarding your security question, yes, since you're rewriting the friendly URL (/Page5) to the actual page (/Content2/Page5.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked into [URLRewriting](http://dotnetblogger.com/post/2009/08/05/URL-Rewriting-Made-Easy-Part-2-%28Extensionless-URLs-IIS7-and-URLReWritingNet%29.aspx)? I suppose you could do it with URLRouting as well, but I'll let someone else answer that route.

## EDIT:

Another option is that if you know the EXACT file path for each file, you can hard code each path using [URLMappings](http://www.developer.com/net/asp/article.php/3581326/URL-Mapping-in-ASPNET-20.htm)

Answer (score 0):

If you're using IIS 7+, you can use the IIS URL Rewrite Module from Microsoft ([link](http://www.iis.net/download/URLRewrite)).

If you're using IIS 6, take a look at [ISAPI Rewrite](http://www.isapirewrite.com/).  I used it a little and it seemed to work pretty well.